# DLL Load Failed for _arpack

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, arpack

Can't quite work around this error. Please any lead.

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-7e54c6764195> in <module>
----> 1 from scipy.optimize import fsolve

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\__init__.py in <module>
    389 
    390 from .optimize import *
--> 391 from ._minimize import *
    392 from ._root import *
    393 from ._root_scalar import *

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py in <module>
     28 from ._trustregion_krylov import _minimize_trust_krylov
     29 from ._trustregion_exact import _minimize_trustregion_exact
---> 30 from ._trustregion_constr import _minimize_trustregion_constr
     31 
     32 # constrained minimization

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_trustregion_constr\__init__.py in <module>
      2 
      3 
----> 4 from .minimize_trustregion_constr import _minimize_trustregion_constr
      5 
      6 __all__ = ['_minimize_trustregion_constr']

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_trustregion_constr\minimize_trustregion_constr.py in <module>
      2 import time
      3 import numpy as np
----> 4 from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator
      5 from .._differentiable_functions import VectorFunction
      6 from .._constraints import (

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py in <module>
    114 from .dsolve import *
    115 from .interface import *
--> 116 from .eigen import *
    117 from .matfuncs import *
    118 from ._onenormest import *

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\__init__.py in <module>
      9 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
     10 
---> 11 from .arpack import *
     12 from .lobpcg import *
     13 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\__init__.py in <module>
     20 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
     21 
---> 22 from .arpack import *

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\arpack.py in <module>
     43 __all__ = ['eigs', 'eigsh', 'svds', 'ArpackError', 'ArpackNoConvergence']
     44 
---> 45 from . import _arpack
     46 import numpy as np
     47 import warnings

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Comment: Are you using any environments?

Comment: Consider using Docker + [Jupyter DataScience notebook](https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/datascience-notebook/) which provides a straightforward ready-to-go environment without any Windows related issues such as `PATH` not being set up properly, `\\` as file separator, compiling issues of various science libraries and missing low-level dependencies for Python science libraries.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like  the scipy had a problem!
I solved it by reinstalling `scipy` with `pip` and it's solved!

```py
pip install scipy
```